# Getting a specific data using button PHP MYSQL MORRIS.JS

Tags: php, mysql, morris.js

Flow of the program:
1. Upon loading of the page I have an SQL query that calculates the average and total sales of all the branches and I generated the buttons for each branch using while loop.
2. When I click the sales button of a specific branch the SQL query should calculate the total and average sales of that branch and display it using MORRIS.JS.

I am having a problem with getting the specific branch in order to display the total and average sales.

PHP Code for button generation for each branch:

```
echo "var content = '<div class=".'content'.">'+
    '$image'+
    '<p class=".'street'.">".$row['street']."</p>'+
    '<span class=".'label'.">Branch:</span>'+
    '<span class=".'details'.">".$row['branch']."</span>'+
    '<span class=".'label'.">Country:</span>'+
    '<span class=".'details'.">".$row['country']."</span>'+
    '<span class=".'label'.">Barangay:</span>'+
    '<span class=".'details'.">".$row['barangay']."</span>'+
    '<span class=".'label'.">Town:</span>'+
    '<span class=".'details'.">".$row['town']."</span>'+
    '<span class=".'label'.">Province:</span>'+
    '<span class=".'details'.">".$row['province']."</span>'+
    '<span class=".'label'.">Phone:</span>'+
    '<span class=".'details'.">".$row['phone']."</span>'+
    '<span class=".'label'.">Email:</span>'+
    '<span class=".'details'.">".$row['email']."</span>'+
    '<span class=".'label'.">Website:</span>'+
    '<span class=".'details'.">".$row['website']."</span>'+
    '<a href='".$row['id']."' class=".'btn-sales'.">View Sales</button>'+
'</div>';
```

Code for calculating the total sales of all the branch and display data using chart via Morris.js:

```
<div id="t-yearly-sales" style="height: 80%;"></div>
<?php
    include "connect.php";
    $sql = "SELECT year, SUM(sales) AS sales FROM tblSales GROUP BY year";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $chart = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $chart .= "{year:'".$row["year"]."', sales:".$row["sales"]."},";
    }                       
?>
<script>
    new Morris.Bar({
      element: 't-yearly-sales',
      data: [<?php echo $chart; ?>],
      xkey: 'year',
      ykeys: ['sales'],
      labels: ['Total Sales'],
      hideHover: 'auto'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the id using ajax call . First change this

```
 '<a href='".$row['id']."' class=".'btn-sales'.">View Sales</button>'
```

To this

```
 "<button onclick='chart(".$row['id'].")' class='btn-sales'>View Sales</button>"
```

Then you make a function that has an ajax call

```
function chart(id)
{
   $.ajax({
      method:GET,
      data:{keyid:id},
      url:'yourphpfunction.php',
      success:function(returnData)
      {
         new Morris.Bar({
         element: 't-yearly-sales',
         data: returnData,
         xkey: 'year',
         ykeys: ['sales'],
         labels: ['Total Sales'],
         hideHover: 'auto'
         });
      }
   });
}
```

On your php file

```
$sql = "SELECT year, SUM(sales) AS sales FROM tblSales where id = " . $_GET['keyid'] . " GROUP BY year";
```

Comment: the declaration is fine what i want sir is when I click the btn-sales button the data of an specific branch the sales of that branch will be calculated

Comment: So it does not have any `js script` error?. What does your sql do ? from i can see it `SUMS` all records. If i get your point maybe you should use `where`  clause

Comment: I got it but how can i transfer the ID of the branch to my sql when I click the button?

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto made some edits. might give it a try

Comment: does my code returns error?. have you tried `console.log`-ing the `returnData` ?

Comment: here is the error Uncaught ReferenceError: chart is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (dashboard.php:1)